# VirtualBox Disk space Expansion

Tags: virtual-machine, diskspace

How to increase the disk space in Oracle VM Virtalbox ?I want to allocate 80 GB .Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If your disk is in .vdi Format, you can use

```
VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_DISK.vdi --resize SIZE_IN_MB
```

If you have a disk in another format, you could convert it to .vdi by cloning it with a destination format.

If you have snapshots, resizing is not possible, so you have to remove them first or use a clone.